# allowing php/apache to delete files in an ftp directory and subfolders

Tags: apache-2.2, php, permissions, chmod

Basically, I am having an issue with a php script being able to move or delete files, and I know it has to do with permissions since that's what the php error from `unlink()` is telling me, but I'm not sure how to fix it. So I'm hoping if I explain the situation, someone might point me in the right direction, for I am a noob when it comes to linux CLI stuff...

Okay so I have an ftp dropbox location let's say it's located at

`/var/ftp/client/dropbox/`

And I have created an ftp account with `pure-ftpd`. So when a file is uploaded to this directory, its owner is `ftp-user` and its group is `ftp-group`, which is what `pure-ftpd` runs as. This directory's user/group is set as `ftp-user` and `ftp-group`, respectively.

So, a 3rd party script is responsible for sending reports (files) to this dropbox location. The ftp account is supposed to have the ability to create subdirs within this directory, to categorize the files.

So for example, the file structure might look like this:

```
/var/ftp/client/dropbox/invoices/
/var/ftp/client/dropbox/invoices/bal_2013-06-01_2013-06-30.pdf
/var/ftp/client/dropbox/reports/
/var/ftp/client/dropbox/reports/visits/
/var/ftp/client/dropbox/reports/visits/bal_2013-06-01_2013-06-30.xlsx
```

The "home" directory `/var/ftp/client/dropbox/` chmod is `drwxrwxr-x`

When a subdir (e.g. `invoices/`) is created by `ftp-user`, it is getting `chmod` of `drwxr-xr-x`

When a file is uploaded (e.g. `invoices/bal_2013-06-01_2013-06-30.pdf`) by `ftp-user`, it is getting `chmod` of `-rw-r--r--`

**Meanwhile...**

I have a php script located in say

`/var/www/client/`

The script is supposed to open the files and do stuff like update database with category names (the subdir names) and file names etc.. and so far all that is fine.  However....

**So here's the problem...**

Then the script is supposed to either move or delete the files (but not the subdirs) depending on reasons. But using `File::delete()` (Laravel 4) or just straight `unlink()` on the `/path/to/file` is returning a "permissions denied" error.

So, it looks like from using `top` that when my script is run, it (apache) is running under `www-user` and `www-group`.  Makes sense that it'd be running as a different user/group.  But what can I do to give permissions to apache/php to move/delete the files?

I have tried putting `www-user` in the the `ftp-group` group, but it's still giving me the "permissions denied" error.  From research, I *suspect* maybe it has to do with a sticky-bit or something, but I'm not sure, and frankly, all this dir/file permission stuff is a little bit over my head at the moment..

Soo... any advice on what to do here?

**edit**

One thought I had was, instead of having *this* script delete/move the files, I could insert the /path/to/files into a database, along with what action needs to be done. And then have a separate script that performs the action, and then put that script on a cronjob as `root` (or as `ftp-user`.. can I do that? I'm not sure..).  I think this should work, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea to do that, and it seems like the better solution would be to sort out permissions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track by adding the www-user to the ftp-group.  Unfortunately, the files you're creating don't have the group write permissions set.  So only the owner (ftp-user) is able to write/delete them.  You need to have those files created with write permissions for the group (ftp-group) as well.  (This would be `rw-rw-r--` instead of `rw-r--r--`)

The default permissions for new files are controlled via something called `umask`.  Pure-FTP supports a umask directive within its configuration file.  Essentially, you'll want to enter `umask 113:003` into the configuration file, or `-U 113:003` on the command line, to get the correct permissions.

Comment: aha, that did the trick! I added a file `/etc/pure-ftpd/conf/Umask` with `113 003` in it and restarted pure-ftpd and it works like a charm, thanks!